# Adding style to a div through JavaScript classList

Tags: javascript

My question might sound very silly as i am new to javascript. I have the following piece of Plain JavaScript code. What i am trying to achieve is to change background-color of the button when its clicked. I am trying to implement this using plain javascript. No jquery or any other framework.

**JS**

```
var save = document.querySelector('.wrapper .content button');
save.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    save.classList.style.background-color = 'red';
});
```

Comment: Maybe using save.classList.style["background-color"] = 'red'; ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do this

```
var save = document.querySelector('.wrapper .content button');
save.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    save.style['background-color'] = 'red';
});
```

You can also access the `background-color` property of style this way

```
save.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

> *CSS properties with a **-** like **(background-color**) are represented in camelCase in Javascript (**backgroundColor**)
>   objects.*

**SNIPPET**

```js
var save = document.querySelector('.con');
save.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    save.style['background-color'] = 'yellow';
    //or  save.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
});
```

```css
.con{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="con"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `element.style.backgroundColor` and not `element.classList.style.background-color`

```js
var save = document.querySelector('.demo');
save.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div class='demo'> Click me </div>
```

---

### Detail

When you write `save.classList.style.background-color` Javascript read a subtraction like `save.classList.style.background - color`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var save = document.querySelector('button');
save.addEventListener('click', function () {    
    save.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```